# Copy filtered rows from worksheet to the last row of another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I've been working on adapting our excel based sales report into an in-house CRM using macros.

This is the macro I've managed to get to work using code found on this site :

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(10), Me.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0)) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
    End If
            Dim xCellColumn As Integer
            Dim xTimeColumn As Integer
            Dim xRow, xCol As Integer
            Dim xDPRg, xRg As Range
            xCellColumn = 10
            xTimeColumn = 11
            xRow = Target.Row
            xCol = Target.Column
                If Target.Text <> "" Then
                If xCol = xCellColumn Then
                    Cells(xRow, xTimeColumn) = Now
                Else
                    On Error Resume Next
                    Set xDPRg = Target.Dependents
                        For Each xRg In xDPRg
                    If xRg.Column = xCellColumn Then
                    Cells(xRg.Row, xTimeColumn) = Now
                End If
                Next
                End If
        Dim a As Range
        For Each a In Intersect(Target, Columns(10), Me.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0))
            If CBool(Len(a.Value2)) Then _
                a.EntireRow.Copy _
                    Destination:=Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        Next a
    End If
bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This works great for our basic needs but whenever an opportunity closes, we'd like it to be transferred below the existing data to 3 separate worksheets based on the result of the opportunity (Won, Lost, Renewed) and removed from the main CRM sheet (aka cut and not copy).  Those values being some of the choices in column 10, the same row used in my script above.

There's a myriad of different scripts around to accomplish some portion of what I want but I unfortunately couldn't get any script I've tried to work on my file, much less work as intended since our situation involves a few different "special" use case (no filters, multiple criterias, existing tables to receive data, etc).

Basically I'm looking to add on to the script above so :

- all rows are still be copied to the Log sheet (Sheet 3)
- when an entry matching either Won, Lost or Renewed is selected, that entire row should be cut from the CRM sheet (Sheet 1)
- That row should be pasted below the existing data in either sheet 2 (won), sheet 5 (lost) and sheet 6 (renewed)

Any help or advice would be more than appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit :

I've continued to work on getting this to work and I managed to get it to work.

But when I cut the row, it also cuts away the formatting of the row including data validation.  Is there any way to cut the data but leave formatting and data validation settings intact ?  Perhaps trough the use of special paste ?

Here's the code I used :

```js
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(10), Me.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0)) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
    End If
Dim xCellColumn As Integer
Dim xTimeColumn As Integer
Dim xRow, xCol As Integer
Dim xDPRg, xRg As Range
xCellColumn = 10
xTimeColumn = 11
xRow = Target.Row
xCol = Target.Column
    If Target.Text <> "" Then
    If xCol = xCellColumn Then
        Worksheets("CRM").Cells(xRow, xTimeColumn) = Now
        Else
            On Error Resume Next
            Set xDPRg = Target.Dependents
            For Each xRg In xDPRg
                If xRg.Column = xCellColumn Then
                    Worksheets("CRM").Cells(xRg.Row, xTimeColumn) = Now
                End If
        Next
    End If

Dim a As Range
For Each a In Intersect(Target, Columns(10), Me.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0))
    If CBool(Len(a.Value2)) Then _
        a.EntireRow.Copy _
        Destination:=Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Next a
    End If
For Each a In Intersect(Target, Columns(10), Me.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0))
    If Target.Value = "Closed Won" Then _
        a.EntireRow.Cut _
        Destination:=Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        Sheets("CRM").Rows(10000).EntireRow.Copy
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Paste
    Next a
For Each a In Intersect(Target, Columns(10), Me.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0))
    If Target.Value = "Closed Lost" Then _
        a.EntireRow.Cut _
        Destination:=Sheet5.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Next a
For Each a In Intersect(Target, Columns(10), Me.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0))
    If Target.Value = "Renewal" Then _
        a.EntireRow.Cut _
        Destination:=Sheet6.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Next a

bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Just a note, you have some unqualified ranges (e.g. `Cells(xRg.Row, xTimeColumn)`, `Columns(10)`, etc..  I'd be sure to add the worksheet that is supposed to be on before it, `Worksheets("SheetName").Cells(...)`.

Comment: Thanks.  I added it to the two lines were it was missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to it to work like I wanted.

Here's the code for anyone else this might help.

The first part inserts the date when a cell is modified.

Second part copies to data to the log page

Third part copies the data to the right tab if it meats the specified criteria and deletes the row from the CRM page.

```js
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(10), Me.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0)) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
    End If
Dim xCellColumn As Integer
Dim xTimeColumn As Integer
Dim xRow, xCol As Integer
Dim xDPRg, xRg As Range
xCellColumn = 10
xTimeColumn = 11
xRow = Target.Row
xCol = Target.Column
    If Target.Text <> "" Then
    If xCol = xCellColumn Then
        Worksheets("CRM").Cells(xRow, xTimeColumn) = Now
        Else
            On Error Resume Next
            Set xDPRg = Target.Dependents
            For Each xRg In xDPRg
                If xRg.Column = xCellColumn Then
                    Worksheets("CRM").Cells(xRg.Row, xTimeColumn) = Now
                End If
        Next
    End If

Dim a As Range
For Each a In Intersect(Target, Columns(10), Me.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0))
    If CBool(Len(a.Value2)) Then _
        a.EntireRow.Copy _
        Destination:=Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Next a
    End If
For Each a In Intersect(Target, Columns(10), Me.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0))
    If Target.Value = "Closed Won" Then _
        a.EntireRow.Copy _
        Destination:=Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
Next a
For Each a In Intersect(Target, Columns(10), Me.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0))
    If Target.Value = "Closed Won" Then _
                a.EntireRow.Delete
    Next a
For Each a In Intersect(Target, Columns(10), Me.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0))
    If Target.Value = "Closed Lost" Then _
        a.EntireRow.Copy _
        Destination:=Sheet5.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Next a
For Each a In Intersect(Target, Columns(10), Me.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0))
    If Target.Value = "Closed Lost" Then _
                a.EntireRow.Delete
    Next a
For Each a In Intersect(Target, Columns(10), Me.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0))
    If Target.Value = "Renewal" Then _
        a.EntireRow.Copy _
        Destination:=Sheet6.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Next a
For Each a In Intersect(Target, Columns(10), Me.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0))
    If Target.Value = "Renewal" Then _
                a.EntireRow.Delete
    Next a

bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```